# Loading/switching DIVs by calling unique functions (on WordPress page)

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, html

I'm more of an HTML/CSS guy, and while I know a bit of basic Javascript, I'm not sure how to code what I'd like to see. I'm trying to do this on a WordPress page.

This is a page that shows upcoming events for a certain province/region of Canada, and has an interactive map at the top.

When a user clicks on a certain province on the map, it calls a function that loads a unique DIV and its content inside another "container" DIV (to keep all content loading in the same spot). All the DIVs for each province/region are on the same page, as WordPress is installed in the root directory, and doesn't allow links to pages (within the same domain) other than the ones it creates.

```
    <div id="map">
    </div>


 <div id="scheduleBox">
// content will be loaded here 
    </div>

<!-- ==== DIV FOR BC EVENTS ===== -->
    <div id="bc">
    <div class="schedule_header">
    <h2>Upcoming Events for British Columbia</h2>
    </div>
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr><!-- TABLE HEADERS -->
    <td class="tableheader">Date</td>
    <td class="tableheader">Time</td>
    <td class="tableheader">City</td>
    <td class="tableheader">Venue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><!-- EVENT #1 -->
    <td class="date">August 01, 2011</td>
    <td class="time">12:00 AM</td>
    <td class="city">Kelowna, BC</td>
    <td class="venue">Venue Name Here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><!-- EVENT #2 -->
    <td class="date">August 01, 2011</td>
    <td class="time">12:00 AM</td>
    <td class="city">Kelowna, BC</td>
    <td class="venue">Venue Name Here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="date">August 01, 2011</td>
    <td class="time">12:00 AM</td>
    <td class="city">Kelowna, BC</td>
    <td class="venue">Venue Name Here</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

 // Event listings for Alberta //

    <div id="ab">
    <div class="schedule_header">
    <h2>Upcoming Events for Alberta</h2>
    ....
    ...
    </div>
    </div>
```

Because of WordPress's limitations, when the user clicks on another province, the previously displayed content is swapped with the new content without referencing a URL or HTML page. It simply grabs content by referencing a DIV id, and loading everything within it.

I have tried using jQuery's append and AJAX functions to switch DIVs, but nothing seems to work. I've also looked at tutorials that switch DIVs, but those rely on external pages.

So, I'm at a loss. I've provided some pseudo-code below that shows a picture of what I'd like to happen:

```
function loadbc() {    // function that loads events for British Columbia
#scheduleBox.hide;      // clear content from the container div if there is any.
#scheduleBox.show;
findDiv("#bc");
#scheduleBox.AddContent("#bc");  // inject the DIV for BC events, and its contents.
fadeIn("fast");
}
```

Perhaps I'm over-complicating things, or missing a few things. In any case, I'd much appreciate some enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `.hide()` is not clearing content its just hidden.
If you want to clear your content then just use next method

`$('#scheduleBox').html('')`;

This will clear everything inside scheduleBox.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BKh4Y/)

I'd say something like this:

```
$("#scheduleBox").children().remove();
$("#scheduleBox").hide();
$("#scheduleBox").append($("#bc"));
$("#scheduleBox").fadeIn("slow");
```